# How to implement a UITextView screen for massive text input

Tags: ios, layout, uitextview, markdown

I need to implement a screen where the user is able to write an Application Letter for a job position.

The main idea is to have a `UITextView` where the user writes what he wants, with a character limit, and the current writing area is visible.

I want the all view to scroll up under the top bar, not just to scroll inside the `UITexView`.

Like this:

[image]
[image]

I also want to implement a Markdown parser for the final text and a keyboard shortcut for Markdown, any ideas on how to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement keyboard shortcut - you have to write your own keyboard in this case, because normally you cannot influence on the keyboards appearance, except of change it to black color.

About markup - you are here on your own again, as you have to look for already made solutions to parse it properly.

As for the `UITextView` - no problems here, just stick it up to the edge of the screen in interface builder with constraints and then it will be just as you would like it to be when you have `UINavigationBar` on top.